# Error response from daemon: Container is not running

Tags: docker

i am new to docker.
i have created a container and tried to connect to it. I run below command.

```
sudo docker exec -it 2e5f0a0f58a0 /bin/bash
```

And getting below output as a error:

```
Error response from daemon: Container 2e5f0a0f58a091ddacd7c462a377e8e2e2fc57d465029e10a0745ccd41379806 is not running
```

Comment: what does `docker ps -a` give you?

Comment: One more thing added to above question is,
i have created a ansible playbook and use docker_image and docker_container module to create docker image and container.

Comment: If I run 
# sudo docker ps -a

sudo docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                 COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                      PORTS               NAMES
2e5f0a0f58a0        ketanskanade/webapp   "/usr/sbin/apache2..."   12 minutes ago      Exited (0) 10 minutes ago                       PHPAPP

Comment: If I create a container manually not by using ansible playbook it works fine

Comment: well, there you go. the container is'nt running. It doesn't display a faulty returncode, meaning the process it ran just terminated. for a more comprehensive answer, i'd need to see the playbook and more info about what you are running in the container.

Comment: Playbook :

  - name: build the image
    docker_image:
      name: ketanskanade/webapp
      tag: latest
      path: /home/ubuntu/docker/
      state: present

  - name: Create a docker container
    docker_container:
      name: PHPAPP
      image: ketanskanade/webapp
      dns_servers: 8.8.8.8
      detach: yes
      force_kill: yes
      network_mode: "bridge"
      published_ports: 0.0.0.0:80:8080
      pull: no
      restart_policy: on-failure
      state: started

Comment: Dockerfile:

`code`
#Select base image
FROM devopsedu/webapp
#FROM nimmis/apache-php5

#Auther for the docekr file
MAINTAINER Rommy Bhuwaliya

#Create a Directory
CMD mkdir /app

# Set the working directory to /app
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the current directory contents into the container at /app
ADD website /app

#Copy apache configuration file
COPY 000-default.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf

#Expose some ports for website
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

#start apache web server
CMD ["/usr/sbin/apache2ctl", "-k", "start"]

Comment: Playbook:

`code`
- name: build the image
    docker_image:
      name: ketanskanade/webapp
      tag: latest
      path: /home/ubuntu/docker/
      state: present

  - name: Create a docker container
    docker_container:
      name: PHPAPP
      image: ketanskanade/webapp
      dns_servers: 8.8.8.8
      detach: yes
      force_kill: yes
      network_mode: "bridge"
      published_ports: 0.0.0.0:80:8080
      pull: no
      restart_policy: on-failure
      state: present
`code`

Comment: It would be nice to update your question by adding all this information you have posted in comments and also by using formatting properly. As it is now, these comments are unreadable.